# How to convert unix timestamp into ISO Date with +5 hours offset in javascript

Tags: node.js, date

I want to get ISO Date from unix timestamp with +5 hours offset. I can get the ISO Date with following code using javascript:

```
unix_time = 1602097200000`
iso_date = new Date(unix_time).toISOString().split('T')
```

How should add +5 hours offset in the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved, In order to get ISO Date from unix timestamp, folowing snippet will do the job.

```
unix_time = 1602097200000
iso_date = new Date(unix_time)
offset_date = iso_date.setHours(iso_date.getHours() + 5);
offset_date = new Date(offset_date).toISOString().split('T');
console.log(offset_date[0])
```

Anyhow, Kindly post if someone has more better approach